# Connecting with Tor

Tags: troubleshooting

I'm getting no response from browser.  (FYI:  I'm a non-savvy tech person).  The browser window opens, I enter  "whatever" and push search and nothing happens.  No unable to connect, or server down, or any error message.
Thanks, Steve

Comment: What OS , what Browser?  Are you even sure the .onion addy is even up / correct,  it is a known fact that several more popular sites will go down randomly to prevent / reduce attacks from other attackers and namely the $bad_man.

Comment: when you open the browser you get a connecting dialog box, does the main start page load? where you can click check tor connection?
can you copy your log from that browser dialog box, or from the onion on the left of the address bar. greeon onion > tor network settings > copy tor log to clipboard and paste it here.
can you access http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion its duckduckgo search engine almost always up edit:
you can also try using bridges if you get no where, depending on your network type you might need to use a bridge you can find info on the tor project website. also depending on the netw